# How can I make a while() go from bottom to top?

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

I wrote a chat system but the messages are showing at the top.  I want them to show at the bottom.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

    $selectChats = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `chats` ORDER BY `cid` DESC LIMIT 10");

        $selectChats->execute();

            while($ChatsRow = $selectChats->fetch()) {

                echo '<p class="field">';
                echo $ChatsRow['time'];
                echo ' ';
                echo '(';
                echo $ChatsRow['username'];
                echo ')';
                echo ': ';
                echo $ChatsRow['message'];
                echo '</p>';

            }

?>
```

Image of what it looks like:

http://puu.sh/3UPpe.png

I want it to go from bottom to top, how can I do this?

Comment: get rid of desc in $selectChats

Comment: For future reference, you can also fetchall into an array and then reverse sort it. But in this case, sounds like you want the results in ASC from the get-go.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. it shows the chats 1-10, when I need it to show the MOST recent. So I NEED DESC, but how can I make them show bottom to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply changing the sort order of your query will help in your situation

```
SELECT * FROM `chats` ORDER BY `cid`
```

Since you would need most recent chats at bottom you can do

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `chats` ORDER BY `cid` DESC LIMIT 10) AS t
ORDER BY `cid`
```

Comment: I tried it but when I do that it disallows messages from being inserted.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  it shows the chats 1-10, when I need it to show the MOST recent.  So I NEED DESC, but how can I make them show bottom to top?

Comment: sorry about that @user2609179 try the updated i forgot to include an alias to the interim table